# What algorithms can associate words together from texts?

Tags: computational-linguistics

What algorithms can associate words together from  texts? I was wondering how [this](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/pranavdixit/trump-loser-search) can be achieved. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Associating word A with related words B, C, D; by training a model on different texts? Or like a keyword search?

Comment: Google for document-term matrices, this is what many search algorithms use.

Comment: Google's algorithm uses features beyond text such as clicks on search results and the changing details of that algorithm are trade secret of Google.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

Go through a lot of tweets, for each tweet: For each word in this tweet, store the word (if not already stored) somewhere and put all other words in this tweet into a list that is connected to this entry. If some word comes up a second (third, ...) time, don't add it, but count +1 instead.

I wrote it for you in Python:

```
tweets = ["Trump is a loser",
          "What a loser man. Trump go home"]
frequencies = {}

for tweet in tweets:
    for word in tweet.split():
        remainder = [otherword for otherword in tweet.split() if not otherword == word]
        try:
            frequencies[word]
        except:
            frequencies[word] = {}
        for otherword in remainder:
            try:
                frequencies[word][otherword] += 1
            except: #no entry yet
                frequencies[word][otherword] = 1

for k,v in frequencies.items():
    print(f"\n{k}:")
    print("\n".join([f"{x[1]} co-occurrence(s): {x[0]}" for x in sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]))
```

Results in:

```
Trump:
2 co-occurrence(s): a
2 co-occurrence(s): loser
1 co-occurrence(s): is
1 co-occurrence(s): What
1 co-occurrence(s): man.
1 co-occurrence(s): go
1 co-occurrence(s): home

is:
1 co-occurrence(s): Trump
1 co-occurrence(s): a
1 co-occurrence(s): loser

a:
2 co-occurrence(s): Trump
2 co-occurrence(s): loser
1 co-occurrence(s): is
1 co-occurrence(s): What
1 co-occurrence(s): man.
1 co-occurrence(s): go
1 co-occurrence(s): home

loser:
2 co-occurrence(s): Trump
2 co-occurrence(s): a
1 co-occurrence(s): is
1 co-occurrence(s): What
1 co-occurrence(s): man.
1 co-occurrence(s): go
1 co-occurrence(s): home

What:
1 co-occurrence(s): a
1 co-occurrence(s): loser
1 co-occurrence(s): man.
1 co-occurrence(s): Trump
1 co-occurrence(s): go
1 co-occurrence(s): home

...
```

You'd have to deal with punctuation marks yourself, also with upper/lowercase.